# RCurl - How to retrieve data from sftp?

Tags: r

I tried to retrieve data from sftp with the below code:

```
library(RCurl)

protocol <- "sftp"
server <- "xxxx@sftp.xxxx.com"
userpwd <- "xxx:yyy"
tsfrFilename <- "cccccc.tsv" 
ouptFilename <- "out.csv"



opts = list(
  #ssh.public.keyfile = "true", # file name
  ssh.private.keyfile = "xxxxx.ppk",
  keypasswd = "userpwd"
)

# Run #
## Download Data
url <- paste0(protocol, "://", server, tsfrFilename)
data <- getURL(url = url, .opts = opts, userpwd=userpwd)
```

and i received an error message: 
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Authentication failure

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With a private key you do not need a password with you username. So your `getURL` statement will be:

```
data <- getURL(url = url, .opts = opts, username="username")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and have just spent an hour trying different things out. What worked for me was changing the format of the private key to OpenSSH.

To do this, I used the key generator package puttygen. Go to the menu item "Conversions" to import the original private key and export to the OpenSSH format. I exported the converted key to the same folder that my original key was in with a new filename. I kept the *.ppk extension

Then I used the following commands:

```
opts <- list(
       ssh.private.keyfile = "<path to my new OpenSSH Key>.ppk"
)

data <- getURL(url = URL,  .opts = opts, username = username, verbose = TRUE)
```

This seemed to work fine.